# Populate QTableWidget using DataBinding

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pyqt4

I want the data retrived from Oracle Database to be used as a content of QTablewidget.

Since My database contains thousands of records it takes more time to populate(using loop) it into QTableWidget. Is there any other option populate it without using (for/while)loops? 
I want to reduce the timetaken to populate.

(1) Currently using Code:

```
connection = self.DB_Connect()
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(str(queryStr))
results = cursor.fetchall()

for row in range(0,len(results)):
    self.dlg.ui.tblWtGIS.insertRow(row)
    record = results[row]                 
    for column in range (0,len(record)):                        
        newitem = QTableWidgetItem(str(record[column]))
        self.dlg.ui.tblWtGIS.setItem(row,column,newitem)
```

(2) I want similar to .NET code as mentioned below

```
adap = New OleDbDataAdapter(query, dbcon)
adap.Fill(ds)
dgdb.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

Comment: Can you use the [QtSQL](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtsql/qtsql-index.html) api to connect to your database?. To use data-bindings you need to use a QTableView + QSQLTableModel.